# Running web app in both Jetty and Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, jetty, jndi

I have a web app which in production I run on Tomcat. It uses the MySQL connector, however it is not bundled up with the war, rather it is included under Tomcat's common lib directory, so that I can access the data source through JNDI.

I would like to do something similar with Jetty (while developing), and more precisely Jetty + Maven. Is there a way for me to include the mysql-connector jar in the classpath when running Jetty through Maven (i.e. not have it bundled in the war file)?

Also I should note that I am using Maven for my build process and have the mysql-connector specified as "provided" scope.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue ?

Comment: @Imran If any answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted by clicking the big empty checkbox. This marks the Question as resolved.

Answer (score 4):

Additinally to previous answer:
you have to add to your jetty plugin in maven config dependency:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <stopKey>blah-blah-blah</stopKey>
                <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                </webAppConfig>
                <jettyEnvXml>${basedir}/src/jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>              
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>8.4-701.jdbc4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

And then you can use provided scope at main project dependencies. I did it right now, and it works. Thank you for your question (and Nishant too)

Comment: Also did this, base on [this](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg02547.html), can confirm it as working ;)

Answer (score 2):

Does not directly answer your question but since I love portability in webapps my war will contain the connector jar and a connection pool (e.g the super duper c3p0). That means that the container will not manage the database connection for me anymore nor will I use JNDI to describe the connection properties. But the webapp is now 100% portable and predictable on tomcat, jetty, resin, jboss etc.

Comment: but OP wants not to package connector jar. Else, it's easy.

Comment: @Nishant: Yes, I mentioned that in my answer. It may add useful info, otherwise I can simply delete the answer.

Comment: please don't delete. I did not mean to offend (and sorry if you felt that way). It sure is a good alternative.

Comment: @Nishant: No offense. I just wanted to add something that I've been through in the past. If it turns to be offtopic, downvoted or flaged I can simply remove it.

Comment: Tomcat 7 will warn you if you have the mysql-connector-java in your war archive.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
<New class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
    <Arg>hd-props</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="java.util.Properties">
            <Call name="load">
                <Arg>
                    <New class="java.io.FileReader">
                        <Arg>cfg/dev-local.properties</Arg>
                    </New>
                </Arg>
            </Call>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

It is a jetty-env.xml, which points to .properties file, which contains all the connect params to DB.

```
    <bean id="jndi" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/hd-props"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="properties" ref="jndi"/>
    </bean>
```

It is a spring config (i'm using spring too)

And then, I call mvn jetty:run, and it works fine...

Comment: does your MySQL dependency say, `provided`?

Comment: honestly, i'm using postgres instead of mysql, but it seems it's no difference what db u are using in this context. No, it has a compile scope... does it matter?

Comment: yeah,actually `compile` scoped artifacts get packaged with war, while `provided` marked artifacts are not. And, the environment (in this case app server) supposed to provide those artifacts. One such artifact is `servlet` as all appservers provide their own implementation.

Comment: Oh, I see.. I just right now tried it, thanks for the idea.. it seems i didn't understand question properly

Comment: Thanks for the response people. The problem I am having is actually more to do with tomcat then jetty. So when I include a jar not necessarily even mysql-connector (in my case its a custom jar file containing some classes I have defined for managing configuration), when I try to run this in tomcat, you get strange behaviour. This is because there are 2 classes from different jars which are actually treated differently by spring and thus I cant

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try using [Maven .war overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) for this purpose, though I don't know if they work with other dependencies.

So basically your project would be

```
parent
|---- original-war
|---- new-war
```

Where your original-war project has the mysql dependency as `<scope>provided</scope>` but the the new-war module is just a pom that has a `<packaging>war</packaging>`, depends on the original war (for the overlay) has the mysql dependency with the compile scope, and runs the jetty plugin (leave the jetty plugin out of the original-war module).  If this works, then you'll have to deal with the minor inconvenience of doing your development in one module but  whatever testing you are doing in maven within another module.