# Where to install JDBC driver for Vaadin app run from IntelliJ using bundled Jetty servlet container?

Tags: maven, jdbc, intellij-idea, jetty, vaadin

I will ultimately be deploying my Vaadin web app to Tomcat servlet container.

In Tomcat, JDBC drivers generally need to be stored outside of the web app, in a separate Tomcat folder. So I do not want to add any JDBC driver as a dependency within my Maven build settings.

In the meantime, while developing I am running the Vaadin 8 or 8.1 web app (created from the `vaadin-archetype-application` Maven archetype) from within IntelliJ 2017.1 using the Jetty servlet container that is somewhere mysteriously bundled (“embedded”?) within the project.

Where can I store my JDBC driver jar file(s) while developing with IntelliJ-Jetty combo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running web app in both Jetty and Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813759/running-web-app-in-both-jetty-and-tomcat)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on wether you use Tomcat or Jetty as an "old fashioned" appserver, or if you use it as an embedded component in your application. The archetype you have used probably assumes the latter (adds jetty-plugin to pom), while it sounds like you want the first scenario. In that case, just install the driver in the tomcat or jetty instance you want to use, and create a run configuration in IntelliJ for that instance. If you need the driver compile-time, add it to the pom with scope "provided". If you want to just have it available to the jetty-plugin, add it as a dependency for that plugin (inside the plugin definition).

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4816657/3066816) for more info about including dependencies only for embedded jetty.